# How to render different content in Vue contitionally

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, parameters, vue-router

I am confused with Vue Routes and sending params as props over all files. I have following structure
[image]
[image]

When I click on card(ProjectDashboard) I want to be redirected to card detail page(ProjectOverview). On Card detail page is sidebar navigation. When I click on navi1 or navi2 I want to display different component on dashboard. Everything stay fixed only dashboard component will be different.

router.js

```
const router = new VueRouter( {
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'ProjectsDashboard',
      component: ProjectsDashboard,
    },
    {
      path: '/project/:id',
      name: 'project',
      props: true,
      component: ProjectOverview,
    },
    {
      path: '/project/:id/something',
      name: 'project',
      props: true,
      component: ProjectOverview,
    },
    {
      path: '/:catchAll(.*)', 
      component: error404,
      name: 'NotFound'
    }
  ],
} );
```

ProjectDashboard.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="m-3">
    <div class="text-center m-2">DASHBOARD</div>
    <div v-for="item in customJsonAllClient" :key="item.id">
      <router-link :to="{name:'project', params:{id:item.id, bexioId:item.bexioId, gitlabId:item.gitlabId, title:item.title}}">
      <b-card-group deck>
        <b-card
          bg-variant="light"
          text-variant="dark"
          class="text-center"
        >
          <b-card-text>
            {{item.title}}
           </b-card-text
          >
        </b-card>
      </b-card-group>
      </router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { BCard, BCardText, BLink, BCardGroup } from 'bootstrap-vue';
import Vue from 'vue';
import { VServices } from '@libTs/vue-base';
import { jsonDataService } from './../services/customJsonData.service';

const SERVICES = VServices({
  json: jsonDataService,
});

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'ProjectsDashboard',
  components: {
    BCard,
    BCardText,
    BLink,
    BCardGroup
  },
  data() {
    return {
      customJsonAllClient: [],
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    await SERVICES.json.getCustomJsonAllClients();
    this.customJsonAllClient = SERVICES.json.customJsonAllClient;
  },
});
</script>
```

ProjectOverview.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <navbar></navbar>
    <site-navbar :id="projectData.id"></site-navbar>

    <div class="sidenav-overlay"></div>
    <div class="app-content content">
      <div class="content-overlay"></div>
      <div class="header-navbar-show"></div>
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <b-card bg-variant="light" text-variant="dark" class="text-center">
          <b-card-text>
            {{ title }}
          </b-card-text>
        </b-card>

        <div v-if="jsonClientsProjects">
          <b-card v-for="item in jsonClientsProjects" :key="item.id">
            <b-card-text>Project id {{ item.id }}</b-card-text>
            <b-card-text>Project name {{ item.name }}</b-card-text>
            <b-card-text>Description {{ item.description }}</b-card-text>
            <b-card-text>
              Project Created: {{ date.getCreatedDate(item.created_at) }}
            </b-card-text>
            <b-card-text>
              Last Project Update :
              {{ date.getDateLastUpdate(item.last_activity_at) }}
            </b-card-text>
          </b-card>
        </div>

        <div v-else>
          <b-card>
            <b-card-text>Project id {{ projectData.id }}</b-card-text>
            <b-card-text>Project name {{ projectData.name }}</b-card-text>
            <b-card-text>Description {{ projectData.description }}</b-card-text>
            <b-card-text>
              Project Created: {{ date.getCreatedDate(projectData.created_at) }}
            </b-card-text>
            <b-card-text>
              Last Project Update :
              {{ date.getDateLastUpdate(projectData.last_activity_at) }}
            </b-card-text>
          </b-card>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { BCard, BCardText, BLink, BCardGroup } from 'bootstrap-vue';
import Vue from 'vue';
import { VServices } from '@libTs/vue-base';
import Navbar from './navbar.vue';
import SiteNavbar from './site-navbar.vue';
import { dateService } from './../services/date.service';
import { bexioDataService } from './../services/bexioData.service';
import { gitlabDataService } from './../services/gitlabData.service';
import { jsonDataService } from './../services/customJsonData.service';

const SERVICES = VServices({
  date: dateService,
  bexio: bexioDataService,
  gitlab: gitlabDataService,
  json: jsonDataService,
});

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'ProjectOverview',
  props: { id: String, bexioId: String, gitlabId: String, title: String },
  components: {
    BCardGroup,
    BCard,
    BCardText,
    BLink,
    Navbar,
    SiteNavbar,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      customJsonAllClient: [],
      jsonClientsProjects: [],
      projectData: [],
      date: SERVICES.date,
    };
  },
  created() {},
  async mounted() {
    await SERVICES.json.getCustomJsonAllClients();
    this.customJsonAllClient = SERVICES.json.customJsonAllClient;

    this.getCorrectUserData();

    await SERVICES.gitlab.getClientsProjects(this.projectData.gitlabId);
    this.jsonClientsProjects = SERVICES.gitlab.jsonClientsProjects;
    this.getCorrectUserData();
  },
  methods: {
    getCorrectUserData() {
      const url = window.location.pathname;
      const pathArray = url.split('/');
      let last = pathArray[pathArray.length - 1];
      let obj = this.customJsonAllClient.find((x) => x.id == last);
      this.projectData = obj;
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

siteNavbar.vue

```
<ul class="navigation navigation-main">
<li class="nav-item active">
<router-link to="/project/:id"> this link should switch to ProjectOverview  </router-link>
</li>
<li class="nav-item active">
<router-link to="/project/:id/something"> this link should switch to some other component  </router-link>
</li>
</ul>
```

router link is on first main vue app.

I can sent data from ProjectDashboard as a param and it show correct data on its detail page but I don't know how I should set up router link in sidebar that it always show correct data for current prop param and how I can render only component which I need.
PS: is it possible to add active class for navi link somehow with routs or I have to create separate function in methods for this?

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is using nested routes.
Check out:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html#nested-named-views
and
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

for active class watch:
https://router.vuejs.org/api/#active-class